# getchar() returns a character that isn’t a newline after I press enter

Tags: c

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    while(getchar() != '\n') {
        printf("\n%d\n", i);
        i++;
    }
    printf("second printf: %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

The expected ouput after I press enter only is:

> second printf: 0

instead of:

> 0
>
> second printf: 1

Why is this happening ?
I am on linux Ubuntu MATE.

Comment: The title of your question does not match the description of the question: The tittle is about "loop", but the description is not. Please edit!

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Try saving the character you read and printing that in the loop.

Comment: Show your actual code

Comment: I believe you are windows user (\r)

Comment: You may want to post details of your platform and exact how you are invoking and interacting with the program.

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Joshua remove `\`` from the line containing `return 0;`

Comment: @CodeIt: I figured as much. I also believe because of the typo the real code differs.

Comment: Your code is working fine [here](https://repl.it/repls/ShyUnrealisticParallelport) it gives the expected output `second printf: 0` when you press `Enter`.

Comment: @GreenTree I get the same result on Linux and Windows, so it's not that.

Comment: Declare `int c;`, change the condition to `while((c = getchar()) != '\n')`, and `printf("%d: (%c)\n", i, c);` in the loop and see what you get.

Comment: This is rather useless question because you don't reveal what kind of terminal setup you have. On *any standard Unix/Linux setup anywhere* when you take a terminal connection afresh and run this program, the behaviour is as expected. What you have is because of your environment, yet you don't disclose any of it here.

Answer (score 2):

So I got some information about anas firari's environment by reading his other questions. This involves some measure of physic debugging.

You are getting input of `\r\n` when you type a newline because your terminal is in raw mode. Older shells used to choke on this by treating `\r` as something that isn't whitespace, but newer ones actually work ok.